# How do you find interpolated points on a sphere / hemisphere from data in spherical coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

How do you interpolate data on the sphere / hemisphere in C++?

I have a bunch of theta, phi spherical coordinates with a density value associated.
[Theta | Phi | Density] for about 100 points.

If I sample a new data point, not captured in the data but on the sphere, How can I find what the interpolated density value should be from the data points?

Splines, RBFs, something else?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Better ask elsewhere. I would guess one way is to use spherical harmonics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: I cross posted in algorthims and math, but I know some people who have done this in C++ that is what I thought it was relevant there too

Comment: you posted on SO with the `C++`, `algrotihm` and `math` tags. You didn't cross post in algorithms and math. To cite from the `math` tag: *any math questions on this size should be programming related*

Comment: To me this looks like a practical programming question about interpolation on a sphere rather than a theoretical one.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like Voronoi tesselation to create a set of (preferably convex) facets from the existing points, and then interpolate within these facets based on proximity to each vertex.

This answer might offer some useful pointers:

[Algorithm to compute a Voronoi diagram on a sphere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545870/algorithm-to-compute-a-voronoi-diagram-on-a-sphere)

Comment: There's [a lengthy thread at ObjectMix](http://objectmix.com/graphics/242663-delaunay-triangulation-sphere-minimal-code.html) on producing the Delaunay triangulation from points on a sphere, with the topic being picked up and shaken like a ragdoll by leading geometric computation light Dave Eberly.  It's basically a job for convex hull in 3D.

Comment: I thought of that, but it does not really interpolate that is more a nN approach