# Thiessen-like polygons out of pre-labeled points

Tags: python, geometry, gis, spatial, voronoi

I have a list of coordinate points that are already clustered. Each point is available to me as a row in a csv file, with one of the fields being the "zone id": the ID of the cluster to which a point belongs. I was wondering if there is a way, given the latitude, longitude and zone ID of each point, to draw polygons similar to Voronoi cells, such that:

- each cluster is entirely contained within a polygon
- each polygon contains points belonging to only one cluster
- the union of the polygons is contiguous polygon that contains all the points. No holes: the polygons must border each other except at the edges. A fun extension would be to supply the "holes" (water bodies, for example) as part of the input.

I realise the problem is very abstract and could be very resource intensive, but I am curious to hear of any approaches. I am open to solutions using a variety or combination of tools, such as GIS software, Python, R, etc. I am also open to implementations that would be integrated into the clustering process.

Comment: One way would be to calculate the Voronoi diagram from all points and merge the cells of those points that belong to the same zone.

Comment: Could you elaborate or give me a link to explain how that could be done?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545870/algorithm-to-compute-a-voronoi-diagram-on-a-sphere) for example.

Comment: But wouldn't this create cells that contain points from different zones?

Comment: The initial Voronoi diagram will have cells with a single point. And then you explicitly merge cells. If you merge correctly, there will never be cells with points from different zones.